# Website running extremely slow on tablet/smartphone devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website up and running for a client on an old dell poweredge 2600 running windows server 2008. Accessing the website via a desktop or laptop works fine. However, when you attempt to access it via a tablet/smartphone, the page loads extremely slow (> 10 minutes to load), or sometimes not at all. Here is the site: www.theringoffirebbq.com. I could use some help figuring out how to increase the response time for tablet/smartphone access; css/html have been optimized for mobile display, so not sure what is causing the bottleneck on these devices. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You could start reviewing the performance of the page (what is taking forever to load). There are some tools to do it in tablets and phones, like Chrome for Android devices: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging Please try to do some research on your own so you can narrow down the problem because right now it's too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images you are using in the top part of the website are too large which means they will render and load slowly on smaller screens. Example: http://www.theringoffirebbq.com/images/like.jpg (2448x3264 pixels/ 0.5mb) .

If you want them to remain large and crisp on larger screens while loading fast on smaller screens you need to implement responsive image control, example: https://responsiveimages.org/

Good luck

Comment: I was switching the images to smaller versions using the media query in the css. The image size I was using for the smaller screens is 860px on the long edge. Is that still too large?